# How can I quickly trigger a mutiny and acquire the Infamous Captain achievement/perk in Pillars of Eternity 2?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity-ii

I'm playing a cruel, aggressive, Bleak Walker Captain. And I want to make sure everyone in the Deadfire knows that they best not mess with me. The best way to do this, that I can see, is to ruthlessly and violently put an end to any thought my crew might have of mutinying against me, to gain the Infamous Captain achievement, and its associated character perk. What's the best and easiest way to achieve this, as early in the game as possible?